# Secure or lock the Azure YAML in GIT Repos, or pipeline

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have two Azure Git Repos, for two teams, each team can only view, and contribute their own repos.

Team1/Repo1

- Entry.yaml

Team2/Repo2

- Extends.yaml

The **repo1** contains YAML file, and content

Entry.yaml owned by Team2, in Repo1

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: repoSource
      type: git
      name: Project1/repo2
extends:
  template: extends.yaml@repoSource
```

extends.yaml in Repo2 are also owned by Team2.

Is there a way to prevent Entry.yaml being modify by Team1, while still remain contributing change to other files on same repos, the reason is prevent unauthorize script run by possible replaces of the the job definition inside the extends.yaml to Entry.yaml with production service connection.

I am also try to find the way to invalidate the CICD job, when it detecting the extends template being change or removed.

Comment: You can't do this in Git, which (by design) completely omits any kind of access control. You *may* be able to do this with some add-on such as AzDO and/or their pipelines and CI/CD system, but if so, the "how" isn't really a Git question.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options (you can as well combined them all together).

1. Using [environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops), you could force a pipeline to only run if they extend a template: [Define approvals and checks - Required template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#required-template):

> With the required template check, you can enforce pipelines to use a specific YAML template. When this check is in place, a pipeline will fail if it doesn't extend from the referenced template.

[image]

2. In Repo1, You can set up branch policies on your main and releases/* branches and require Team2 to review changes if the `Entry.yaml` file has changed. See [Automatically include code reviewers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#automatically-include-code-reviewers)

[image]

3. Then Back to environment, you could force a pipeline to run from specific branches. [Define approvals and checks - Branch control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#branch-control):

> Using the branch control check, you can ensure all the resources linked with the pipeline are built from the allowed branches and that the branches have protection enabled. This helps in controlling the release readiness and quality of deployments. In case multiple resources are linked with the pipeline, source for all the resources is verified. If you have linked another pipeline, then the branch of the specific run being deployed is verified for protection.

[image]

Combining these, you should be able to achieve what you'd like in a collaborative way.